# Killing Fontaine

Tags: bioshock

Throughout the game I didn't bother using my little health to get little sisters for ADAM.  The result is a very small health and EVE bar. To top it off, I have only two health kits left. Is there any easy way to kill him without having to replay the entire game?

Comment: Edited for spelling (I was wondering who the heck "Fountain" was =)  I don't have an answer to your question though.  He's tough even with full health and eve unlocked on harder difficulties.  Hopefully someone will provide a good answer for you.  Good luck!

Comment: You don't have to redo the whole game. You will just need to back track. It will take time and that is about it. You can get back to the other areas so don't worry. Guess you learned your lesson for bioshock though :p

Answer (score 1):

I have two good tactics to kill Fontaine easily.

1:

Take two wrench jockeys, add one part bloodlust, mix in a couple spootboosts, and add electric flesh to taste.

You end up as an unstoppable wrench maniac who can charge at Fontaine and then beat the ever living hell out of him. While regaining so much health each hit that you dont have to dodge his attacks... or even use health packs.

2:

Shoot at him while running in circles around him but take care of your distance. You will only get hit like 1-2 times in the whole fight if you do well.

Comment: The OP says they didn't hardly get little sisters so I doubt they can equip all those perks. Though good idea for someone who did.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to play the game all over again starting from scratch, but it might be a good idea to backtrack already-visited areas.

There's a TON of stuff you pick up before the final battle, and you can use all of that to take out big daddies in previous levels. The 25% damage reduction from the suit will help make most little sister encounters fairly easy as well.

Answer (score -2):

The fastest way to kill him? Well that's easy. Use the shotgun and upgraded pistol! Also keep your distance from him.